# Syntax in PDO when using >= and <=

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code and the print_r return Array() and not the data I expect.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT sc.classID, sc.longDesc, si.specItemName, si.itemCost, scp.shipUpgradeCost, scp.shipUpgradePrice FROM shipclasses sc JOIN specialitems si ON sc.specItemID=si.specItemID JOIN shipcostingpricing scp ON sc.classID=scp.classID WHERE sc.classID>=:currentclass  AND sc.classID<=:upgradeclass');

            $stmt->bindParam(':currentclass', $currentclass, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upgradeclass', $upgradeclass, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $upgradeInfo = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

When I run this query from sql like this:

```
SELECT sc.classID, sc.longDesc, si.specItemName, si.itemCost, scp.shipUpgradeCost, scp.shipUpgradePrice FROM shipclasses sc JOIN specialitems si ON sc.specItemID=si.specItemID JOIN shipcostingpricing scp ON sc.classID=scp.classID WHERE sc.classID>=2  AND sc.classID<=5;
```

it return the data I expect it to return.  I believe that PDO has an issue with >= and <=.  Anyone that can help me please?

Comment: `fetchALL` -> `fetchAll`, try checking the errors without that we can`t help so much

Comment: I get no error returns just an empty array.  I check if I get the variables inside the function and I do.

Comment: Both `>=` and `<=` are perfectly fine. Enable error_reporting and PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING or something though, and debug the variable contents again. PDO itself doesn't modify much of the query (except for emulated prepares with strings). Also use some newlines in the SQL query for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot to add:`$stmt->execute();` before the line `$upgradeInfo = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sc.classID>=:currentclass  AND sc.classID<=:upgradeclass you could use

```
sc.classID between (:currentclass  AND :upgradeclass)
```